# Android database and connection to the cloud

Tags: java, android, database, azure, xamarin

I'm developing and Android app which provides content to the user.
I want to store the information of the data in a database on the cloud and locally, and to store the actual content also on the cloud, and access it via the information on the database.
I also want to be able to show the user content based on a date, and to check for that frequently.
I would also like to be able to update the content over the web, and show the user news and updates on the fly.
I'm new to this, and would like to understand this. I read all sorts of terms, but not sure which I need for what. GCM, Content Provider, SyncAdapter, database, AsyncTask, etc..
If someone could please give me an overview of how to do what I want, with an explanation, I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately your question is off topic for StackOverflow: This is really broad and opinion-soliciting, regarding the topic of working with data remotely. As far as your terms go, they have little to do with how you build your app - you're mixing specific implementation details (e.g. AsyncTask) with general database topics.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie. I feel lost in all of this and would just like some guidance and where to start from.

Comment: I get that. But your question doesn't really fit here, since it's an open-ended type of thing. i suggest looking for a tutorial on android + database. Also look on the Azure site to see what type of mobile app + android documentation is there. Then, come back here to ask specific questions.

Comment: OK. The problem is that I'm not sure which tool I need for each purpose, so I don't know what to search for exactly...

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store the information of the data in a database on the cloud
>   and locally, and to store the actual content also on the cloud, and
>   access it via the information on the database.

About this requirement, I recommend you can use Azure Offline Data Sync feature to sync up your local and cloud data. Please refer to this documents:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-offline-data/

> I would also like to be able to update the content over the web, and
>   show the user news and updates on the fly.

Notification Hub Service is for pushing the message to client and customer, if you want to use the similar feature, please refer to this documents :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview/#integration-with-app-service-mobile-apps